# Why does my Android Activity remain empty after acquiring permissions and add list data to it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-permissions

This is my main activity which has the methods for requesting permissions for reading calendar and call phone,which get the events from the calendar extract phone number etc,and display it on the activity.But it remains empty for the first launch after giving the permissions,for the next launch all the data comes up,why does this happen?

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // get the listview

            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            getPermissionToDialToAContact();
            getPermissionToReadCalender();
            // preparing list data


            if (listDataHeader != null && listDataChild != null) {


                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


                // Listview Group click listener
                expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                int groupPosition, long id) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                // Listview Group expanded listener
                expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    }
                });

                // Listview Group collasped listener
                expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    }
                });

                // Listview on child click listener
                expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     callPosition=   phoneNumber.size();
                        if(childPosition<callPosition){

                            dialContact(phoneNumber,childPosition);


                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }


            }}
          @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case READ_CALENDER: {

                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.i("mainactonreqpermethod ","mainactonreqpermethod");
                        RuntimeData.setsCalendarData(getCalender(null));
                        prepareListData();

                    } else {
                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    }
                    return ;
                }
                // other 'case' lines to check for other
                // permissions this app might request




                case  CALL_PHONE: {

                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                    } else {
                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private void getPermissionToReadCalender() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)) {
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},
                        READ_CALENDER);
            }else {

                RuntimeData.setsCalendarData(getCalender(null));
                prepareListData();//adding data to list
            }

        }
     private void prepareListData() {
        //   mEventDesc=mData.getEventTitle();
        if (RuntimeData.getsCalendarData()!=null){
            Log.i("runtimedata","runtimedata");
            mData = RuntimeData.getsCalendarData();
            Log.i("runtimedatatomdata","runtimedatatomdata");
        }
        Log.i("list daataheader", "list daataheader" +mData.getEventTitle());
        if(mData.getEventTitle()!=null) {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            phNum=new ArrayList<String>();
            child1=new ArrayList<String>();
            //   listDataHeader = mData.getEventTitle();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            Log.i("list daataheader", "list daataheader" + listDataHeader);
            Log.i("list daatachild", "list daatachild" + listDataChild);
            // Adding child data

            listDataHeader.add(mData.getEventTitle().get(0));
//            listDataHeader.add(mData.getEventTitle().get(1));
//            listDataHeader.add(mData.getEventTitle().get(2));
          mEventData=  extractDescription(mData);

//            listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
//            listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
//            listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");
            // Adding child data
            if(mEventData!=null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mEventData.getPhoneNumber().size(); i++) {
                    phNum = mEventData.getPhoneNumber();
                    child1.add(phNum.get(i));
                    Log.i("list daatachild", "list daatachild" + String.valueOf(phNum));

                }
                Log.i("list daataheader", "list daataheader" +child1.size());
                child1.add(mEventData.getMeetingID().get(0));
                child1.add(mEventData.getMeetingPassWord().get(0));
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), child1);
            }}


        private void getPermissionToDialToAContact() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                        CALL_PHONE);
            }else {


            }

        }



    }
```

Comment: Provide a minimal example

Comment: updated my post @Jeroen Heier

Comment: You removed `prepareListData()` from the code. Don't just make a minimal example. Make it also complete. See about [mcve]

Comment: updated my post..@cricket_007

Comment: after add data try to add notifydatasetchanged to adapter

Comment: i didnt get you.. could you please explain me in detail? @IshanFernando

Comment: Where do you initialize listDataHeader object? @yacky

Comment: in prepareListData() @IshanFernando

Comment: add listAdapter.notifydatasetchanged() at the end of the prepareListData @yacky

Comment: i have 2 permissions and after one permission, the next one is not popping up, if i close and open the app again then its popping up @IshanFernando

Comment: Add permission check to a one list and check it in a on time

Comment: Try this code http://pastebin.com/8sJSyLvE